ssh into Azure VM from local MacOS terminal using Bastion tunnel
I have a UAT Bastion-enabled Management VM in Azure.
I have already copied my public ssh-key into the machine.
I am able to access the machine using web-browser.
However, I wish to connect via terminal due to familiary and ease-of-use.
I wish to connect to the VM from local terminal using the below command -
az network bastion ssh --name MyBastionHost --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
--target-resource-id vmResourceId --auth-type ssh-key \
--username xyz --ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa

This gives me a 'bastion' is misspelled or not recognized by the system. error on local.
az cli version details -
  "azure-cli": "2.67.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.67.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
  "extensions": {}
}

Local machine OS - MacOS
Remote VM - Ubuntu 22.04
Is bastion support disabled for this tenant ? Do I need to check any logs to find out ?

In order to connect to a Linux VM using the az network bastion ssh cmdlet, you may need to follow the prerequisites specified in the MS DOC.

The error message bastion' is misspelled or not recognized by the system is occurring because the Bastion extension is not installed on your laptop. To resolve this, run the command az extension update --name bastion to install the Bastion service


This gives me a 'bastion' is misspelled or not recognized by the system. error on local.

The error you are encountering is due to the Bastion extension not being installed on your laptop
To resolve this, run the command below to install the Bastion service
az extension update --name bastion

Once the extension is installed, make sure to verify the Bastion installation.
az extension show --name bastion


Below are the prerequisites to run the az network bastion ssh.Follow the MS Doc for more details

Bastion supports the Standard and Premium tiers, along with Native client support option enabled. For more details, refer to the MS DOC.

After configuring all the settings, I am able to connect to the Linux VM using az network bastion ssh

